# Can the waiting time in Wait Acitivity be variable?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am asking this, because I need to check whether or not a file has been already copied by some pipe line in a different suscription. Thus,I need to check on time basis this event, I want to increase the value of the waiting activity each time the copy activity fails, because this last one did not find the desired file.

Answer (score 0):

You could make wait time an expression, and pass different value to it each time.
Please take a look at the example [in this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-filter-activity#example).